# Printing to a Local Printer While Using VPN

Tags: vpn, printing

I use Cisco's AnyConnect VPN client for Mac to access my work network from home. While using the VPN I am unable to connect to my home printer. Is there any way around this? Is it possible to add my home printer while using VPN?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This largely depends upon the settings that your network administrator has set up for your VPN connection.

It is possible for them to require that all traffic travel through the VPN tunnel, at which point, no, you will not be able to connect to a networked printer in your home.

It is also possible for them to allow traffic that is not bound for your organization, to be transmitted outside the VPN tunnel, at which point you should be able to access your network print and other network resources in your home.

I would check with your network administrator on this...  he/she will be best able to help you out.

Comment: I guess the question should be: IF it were possible, how would one go about it? If nobody else is able to answer that question I'll go ahead and mark yours accepted.

Comment: If whoever set up the VPN set it up as a split tunnel, then your Mac would already be able to communicate with your networked printer while the VPN is active....  Assuming it can communicate while the VPN is inactive.    There is little you should need to do.